# How to get woocommerce products by shipping states

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Make the select field multiselect**

```
function woocommerce_wp_select_multiple( $field ) {
    global $thepostid, $post, $woocommerce;

    $thepostid              = empty( $thepostid ) ? $post->ID : $thepostid;
    $field['class']         = isset( $field['class'] ) ? $field['class'] : 'select short';
    $field['wrapper_class'] = isset( $field['wrapper_class'] ) ? $field['wrapper_class'] : '';
    $field['name']          = isset( $field['name'] ) ? $field['name'] : $field['id'];
    $field['value']         = isset( $field['value'] ) ? $field['value'] : ( get_post_meta( $thepostid, $field['id'], true ) ? get_post_meta( $thepostid, $field['id'], true ) : array() );

    echo '<p class="form-field ' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '_field ' . esc_attr( $field['wrapper_class'] ) . '"><label for="' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ) . '</label><select id="' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $field['name'] ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $field['class'] ) . '" multiple="multiple">';

    foreach ( $field['options'] as $key => $value ) {

        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . ( in_array( $key, $field['value'] ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';

    }

    echo '</select> ';

    if ( ! empty( $field['description'] ) ) {

        if ( isset( $field['desc_tip'] ) && false !== $field['desc_tip'] ) {
            echo '<img class="woocommerce-help-tip" data-tip="' . esc_attr( $field['description'] ) . '" src="' . esc_url( WC()->plugin_url() ) . '/assets/images/help.png" height="16" width="16" />';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="description">' . wp_kses_post( $field['description'] ) . '</span>';
        }

    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

**Add the shipping states multi select field to the products shipping section**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'add_shipping_state_option' );
function add_shipping_state_option() {
  global $product_object;

  woocommerce_wp_select_multiple( array(
    'id' => '_shipping_states[]',
    'label' => __( 'Shipping States', 'woocommerce' ),
    'options' => WC()->countries->get_states( 'US' ),
    'value' => $product_object->get_meta( '_shipping_states' ),
    //'multiple' => true,
    //'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-full',
    'description' => 'Select multiple states the product can be shipped to1',
    'desc_tip' => 'Select multiple states the product can be shipped to2',
  ) );
}
```

**Save the custom field value as meta key value pair**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_shipping_state_option' );
function save_shipping_state_option( $product_id ) {
  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  $states = isset( $_POST['_shipping_states'] ) ? array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['_shipping_states'] ) : array();
  //var_dump($states);
  //exit;
  $product->update_meta_data( '_shipping_states', $states );
  $product->save();
}
```

**Get the products by the selected shipping states**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_shipping_state' );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_shipping_state');
function filter_products_by_shipping_state( $q ) {
    $states = null;
    if(isset($_GET['shipping_states'])) {
        $states = explode(",", $_GET['shipping_states'] );
    }
    //var_dump($states);
    if ( ! empty( $states ) ) {
        $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => '_shipping_states',
            'value' => $states,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
    //print_r( $q );
    return $q;
}
```

Expecting to get the products by selected states but not working as expected

the Metadata stored for the product in DB's wp_postmeta table:
`1465 | 242 | _shipping_states | a:3:{i:0;s:2:"AL";i:1;s:2:"AK";i:2;s:2:"AZ";}`

http://localhost/foocommerce/shop-2/?shipping_states=AL,AK,AZ
The above URL should fetch products that are capable to ship to above states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `meta_query` with the `IN` comparison with the serialized array you have in the post meta (it's serialized as a string).

Your query *may* work if you save each state as a separate meta data, but I can't really test it right now. As always, watch out for typos.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_shipping_state_option' );
function save_shipping_state_option( $product ) {
  $states = isset( $_POST['_shipping_states'] ) ? array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['_shipping_states'] ) : array();
  $product->delete_meta_data( '_shipping_states' );
  foreach( $states as $state ) {
     $product->add_meta_data( '_shipping_states', $state );
   }
}
```

Comment: This works but there is one correction to the statement for adding the meta data.

`$product->add_meta_data( '_shipping_states', $state, false );`

Comment: Are you sure you need that? [`$false` is the default](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a9434605e8d017a16b3ab5a62cd396037a1fa08/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L419).

Comment: Yeah, the default statement didn't work in my case and I had to explicitly mention the false & apparently, the documentation says `$unique` is an optional value if we needed to save unique meta values.

https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_dataadd_meta_data/

Comment: It's optional because it defaults to `false` at least as far as I can tell so that's weird. `true` would make it so that you effectively only have 1 meta field called `_shipping_states` which wouldn't work for you as you appear to need several.